# Rails - Error installing Gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Im newbie starting to learn ruby/rails. While i was trying to setup WeBRICK to run, an error related to the libmysql.dll appeared, so ive downloaded an dll from an older version of mysql and tried again, but the error kept. Then i read that the problem was that my computer is 64bit and the gem mysql2 installed apparently is 32bit, that way i uninstalled that gem and tried to do the following workaround:

1) download mysql connector 32 bits
2) gem install mysql --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=C:/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32

the problem now is that im getting the following error:
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EEXIST)
File exists - C:

So, now i cant even install the mysql2 gem

Can you guys help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to run ruby on rails on windows. mac or linux will be better.

if you can't change your OS. you can try this:

http://eric.cloud-mes.com/2012/04/1/install-Ruby-1.9.3-and-Rails-3.2.3-on-Windows-7.html

Comment: Please do not simply link to an external site, if that link dies your answer becomes useless.

Comment: hmm. paste the content here ?

Comment: I appreciate the help regarding ruby and rails install, however at this time i need some help with this error on the installation of mysql gem